# Ruby selenium webdriver find specific svg elements

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have the below html in which am trying to find all the `svg` elements inside `div.container-fluid.container-results >div >ul >li` only and I dont want the svg elements inside `div.container-fluid.container-results >div >ul >div.result-controls`  for a given `row_number` parameter where row_number represents `div[contains(@class,'invoice-result-row')][contains(@id,#{row_number.to_i-1})]`

```
<div class="container-fluid container-results">
   <div class="invoice-result-row" id="0">
      <ul>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Submitted">
               <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green SubmittedIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Sent">
               <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green SentIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Pending">
               <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green PendingIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-file-label-column"><span>validated.txt</span></li>
         <li class="invoice-client-company-column"><span>QA-CP-PP-TRUNK</span></li>
         <li class="invoice-reference-column"><span>T12345638800</span></li>         
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="invoice-result-row" id="1">
      <ul>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Processing">
               <svg class="glyphicon-spin ProcessingIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#refresh"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delivered">
               <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green DeliveredIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-file-label-column"><span>Pending.txt</span></li>
         <li class="invoice-client-company-column"></li>
         <li class="invoice-reference-column"></li>
         <div class="result-controls">
            <li class="invoice-delete-column"></li>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="invoice-result-row" id="2">
      <ul>
         <li class="invoice-process-status-column">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Submitted">
               <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green SubmittedIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="invoice-file-label-column"><span>validated - Copy.txt</span></li>
         <li class="invoice-client-company-column"><span>QA-CP-PP-TRUNK</span></li>
         <li class="invoice-reference-column"><span>T12345638799</span></li>
         <div class="result-controls">
            <div class="attachment">
               <li class="invoice-add-attachment-button-column"><a><button>ADD ATTACHMENTS</button></a></li>
               <input type="file" multiple="" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <li class="invoice-sign-button-column"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><button>SIGN</button></a></li>
            <li class="invoice-draft-button-column"><a><button>DRAFT</button></a></li>
            <li class="invoice-delete-column">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete">
                  <svg class="glyphicon-trash deleteIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                     <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                  </svg>
               </a>
            </li>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do this in in Ruby using Selenium wendriver as below but its throwing `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"svg"}` on the `li` elements which doesnt have `svg` element.

```
rows = driver.find_elements(:css => "div.container-fluid.container-results >div >ul")
    rows[row_number.to_i-1].find_elements(:xpath => "./li").each do |it| 

     if !it.find_element(:tag_name, "svg").nil?
         iconClass = it.find_element(:tag_name, "svg").attribute('class')
          puts "icon #{iconClass}"
        end
end
```

I am just getting started on ruby programming with selenium, Can someone please help me fixing this issue?

Comment: Can you try using a xpath for `SubmittedIcon` as `//svg[@class='glyphicon-upload-green SubmittedIcon']`

Comment: `div.container-fluid.container-results >div >ul > li > a > svg` this will take you to svg but it will not be unique

Comment: @KishanPatel I dont want it to hardcode, it has to be generic enough so that my selenium script can be run on different pages..yes I tried the same `div.container-fluid.container-results >div >ul > li > a > svg` but I couldnt eliminate the other unwanted `svg` elements

Comment: Yes You can use xpath to eliminate those by using indexing. `css` cannot

Comment: How do I use xpath with indexing?

Comment: What I see is only the classname changes for each `svg`. So if you dont want `xpath` to be hardcoded then store all those in an array and pass that array in xpath

Comment: I cannot hardcode the entire class name but I can check for css class which has `Icon`  like  `//svg[contains(@class,'Icon')]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141693/discussion-between-kishan-patel-and-ranpaul).

Comment: @RanPaul  if you are ready to use Ruby Binding, please choose WATIR, it's a very nice wrapper for Ruby Binding, you don't have to write xpath, WATIR will write for you, apart from implicit wait of selenium  WATIR add three more wait  present?,enabled?,writable?(if it's text field), More than that WATIR regain stale element so page refreshing does not affect WATIR and also many nice syntax for table iteration.

Comment: @Gopal I never worked on WATIR, could you please one example in my scenario? so that I can give it a try

Comment: I give u an easy example to understand WATIR will convert `b.element(text: username).send_keys 'hi' ` into. Selenium equivalent of `driver.find_element(:xpath "//*[normalize-space()='username']).send_key 'hi'` and I'd if you bind like `b.button(text: 'username').send_keys 'hi' `then it will convert into  `driver.find_element(:xpath "//button[normalize-space()='username']).send_key 'hi'` so you don't have to write xpath and also in waiting technique it  defeats everything. It waits for exists?, presents?,enabled?, writable? And no stale element problem and you can iterate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Our Discussion, following is the way :

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath => getCPLineSelector).each do |tag| 
icon = tag.find_element(:tag_name, "svg").attribute('class') 
puts "svg class = #{icon}" 
end 

def getCPLineSelector() 
".//div[contains(@class,'container-results')]//div[contains(@class,'invoice-
result-row')][contains(@id,#{row_number.to_i-1})]//ul/li/a" 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CSS selector, `"[id='2'] > ul > li > a > svg"`. Throw that in a function, pass in the row number, and it looks something like this

```
def find_svg(rowNo)
  driver.find_element(:css, "[id='#{rowNo}'] > ul > li > a > svg")
```

Hopefully I got the syntax right... I don't know Ruby.